# Application Deployment in VS 2013 express

Tags: c#, deployment, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to deploy my C# windows forms application using Visual Studio 2013 Express.  I have followed the guide on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wtzawcsz.aspx but when I try to create a new deployment project, the option to choose it is not there.  Is there an additional package I need to download perhaps?  I'm not sure how to deploy it if I can't create a new deployment project.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I guess I didn't have the correct add-ins installed.  However, I was able to use a quick & easy tool to publish my application.  I simply right-clicked on my solution in the solution explorer, and then clicked publish, and followed all the steps in the wizard.